# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 195,Token in error = AS ]

Tags: c#

While trying to insert data to my SQLCe db i get the following error.

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 195,Token in error = AS ]

Heire is my code.

```
 _connection.Open();
        cmd.Connection = _connection;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO result"+
                     "(Section_name, Qno, Answ, Exame_id, User_id, Start_time, End_time)"+
                    "SELECT  b.sectionname, b.Qno, b.Answ, b.Exame_id AS Expr1, b.User_id, b.Start_time, b.End_time"+
                    "FROM   Question AS a INNER JOIN"+
                     "Solve_Student_question AS b ON a.SubQno = b.Qno AND a.Section_name = b.sectionname"+
                    "WHERE  (b.User_id = '" + userid + "')";

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            _connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee) { }
        _connection.Close();
```

it Will give an error line at  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); error mesage 
  There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 195,Token in error = AS ]
Where is i am wrong.

Comment: Try removing the `as expr1` and try

Comment: @shree.pat18 :- yes i try this but still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This for commmand text, I have add spaces.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO result" +
                     "(Section_name, Qno, Answ, Exame_id, User_id, Start_time, End_time)" +
                    " SELECT  b.sectionname, b.Qno, b.Answ, b.Exame_id AS Expr1, b.User_id, b.Start_time, b.End_time " +
                    "FROM   Question AS a INNER JOIN " +
                     "Solve_Student_question AS b ON a.SubQno = b.Qno AND a.Section_name = b.sectionname " +
                    "WHERE  (b.User_id = '" + userid + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks wrong.

1. Writing database code by hand 2014? There's automatic data layers for that.
2. Building sql in strings, opening up for possible sql injections? Use sql parameters.
3. Swallowing all exceptions, no matter what? How will you know when something fails?

Your issue, however, is probably that you lack spaces in your string, specifically after FROM and INNER JOIN, and before WHERE. Look at the *resulting* string, not your code.

```
"...b.End_timeFROM..."
"...INNER JOINSolve_Student_question..."
"...b.sectionnameWHERE..."
```