# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

This code causes an error when I try to execute it.

My requirement get latest inserted incrementation id

```
_connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = _connection;

cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Finalresult(Section_name, userId, examid) Select Section_name, User_id, Exam_id from result" +
                  "WHERE (User_id = '" + userid + "' Exam_id='" + examis + "' And Section_name='" + section + "')SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

Int32 newId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Error occurs at line

```
Int32 newId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Error is

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: User_id,Exam_id is integer?

Comment: Duplicate of ["Error parsing the query" while getting @@Identity from SQL Server CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514341/error-parsing-the-query-while-getting-identity-from-sql-server-ce) - you cannot do this in SQL Server CE - see ErikEJ's answer to this other question for a solution

Comment: 'And' is missing in Where clause  "WHERE  (User_id = '" + userid + "' And Exam_id='" + examis + "' And Section_name='" + section + "')SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

Answer (score 3):

You need a few changes here, like adding error handling. To get the reason behind the exception, you need to check the `Errors` property of the exception:

```
try
{
    //Your code here
}
catch (SqlCeException e)
{
    foreach (SqlCeError error in e.Errors)
    {
        //Error handling, etc.
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}
```

Doing that, it will tell you exactly what the error is.

I think your `User_id` and `Exam_id` 'parameters' are being treated as strings in the SQL statement, as you are surrounding it with single quotes. At a guess, this will be your problem along with missing logic operators in the WHERE clause.

**However don't do parameterization this way!** You leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks when you concatenate your query this way. There's lots of articles and information on MSDN on how to do this, or take a look at this from Jeff Atwood - http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

**Update**

Ok, to break it down further, based on the comment by **marc_s**, you can't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in SQL CE. So you're looking at doing this:

*A parameterized insert:*

```
    var sqlString = "Insert into Finalresult(Section_name, userId, examid) Select Section_name, User_id, Exam_id from result " +
                      "WHERE (User_id = @userId AND Exam_id = @examId AND Section_name = @sectionName"

    cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", userid); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@examId", examId); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sectionName", section); 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

*And then on the **same** connection (but different command of course), get the inserted id:*

```
cmd.Connection = _connection;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@identity";
Int32 newId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I haven't tested or compiled this, so just take it as an idea/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If userid ,Examids are int then don't use single quotes.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Finalresult(Section_name, userId, examid) Select Section_name, User_id, Exam_id from result" +
              " WHERE (User_id = " + userid + " Exam_id=" + examis + " And Section_name='" + section + "')SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Comment: try this but give error "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 110,Token in error = ( ]"

Comment: (Edit) have added the space between result" + " WHERE...
Try now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551072/there-was-an-error-parsing-the-query-token-line-number-1-token-line-offset/22551231#22551231

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your query. Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Finalresult(Section_name, userId, examid) Select Section_name, User_id, Exam_id from result" +
                  " WHERE (User_id = '" + userid + "' AND Exam_id='" + examis + "' And Section_name='" + section + "')SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```