# Accessing SqlCeException on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am getting `SqlCeException` in my WP8 application. The message says only:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in
Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

As you can see, it is not very specific as to why did it happen. After some googling I found an advice to inspect the exception further by accessing its `Errors` property ([link to discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551369/an-exception-of-type-system-data-sqlserverce-sqlceexception-occurred-in-system)). However, I am not able to import the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException` into my code. Therefore in consequence I am not really able to access any more information about the exception. How can I import this exception to my project so I could work with it? The only idea I got was to add Entity framework, but for some reason NuGet fails to install it.

**EDIT:**
For further generations, I am still not able to access it, even the Reflections seems to reject messing with it (`MethodAccessException` thrown when I tried to access the value of `Errors` property of the `SqlCeException`). At least the `SqlCeException.ToString()` method returns quite a meaningful description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551369/an-exception-of-type-system-data-sqlserverce-sqlceexception-occurred-in-system

Comment: I am working with Linq to SQL. The exception occurs during the database creation - obviously some problem with my mapping. But The query is not important. I can debug it as soon as I get access to the SqlCeException. I just need to know how to add it to the code to be able to access its Errors property.

Comment: You cannot access SqlCeException on Windows Phone, so you must share your code, so we can help you fix the bug you have - or use elimination to find out where the error is

Comment: This sucks.. I'll try the hard way, hopefully I'll learn more.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to an SQL db from Windows phone, the best way it to create a REST Web Service which connects to your db and start consuming it.

Comment: I am speaking about a local SQL db, which is indeed possible. Check for instance [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ what kind of data you want to store and how many of them you would say ?

Comment: that is totally unimportant. All I want is to access the SqlCeException to ask it what is really the problem. I know that there is a problem (obviously), and I know I could debug it using elimination technique. However, it seems like a cumbersome and not robust way to go, so I was hoping to get a hint on how to get to the errors of the exception.